# Opposite to jQuery .remove

Tags: jquery

I have an input form I am trying to remove/add on a click function.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#1").click(function () {
            $("#1").hide("");
            });
            $("#1").click(function () {
                 $("#twitter").remove();
            });
            $("#1").click(function () {
            $("#2").show("");
            });

                    $("#2").click(function () {
            $("#2").hide("");
            });
            $("#2").click(function () {
            $("#1").show("");
            });
            }); 
 </script>

 <span id="1">
 <img align="left" src="../images/twitter_blue.png" width="30px;" style="margin:5px;"/>
 <div>Share as @<?php echo $_SESSION['username']  ?></div>
 </span>
 <img align="left" id="2" src="../images/twitter_white.png" width="30px;" style="margin:5px;display:none;"/>
  <input id="twitter" type="hidden" name="twitter" value="yes"/>
```

You can see that on click of the span id="1" it removes the image and the input form. And when you click on the img id="2" it hides that one and bring backs the original image. How can I bring back or add the input form that I originally remove on the click of the img id="2". Is there a function that is opposite of .remove?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: api.jquery.com - just peruse for 30 mins - it will blow your mind.  The problem with asking for specific methods is sometimes you don't even know there is a question to ask.  Learn the whole API and become a NINJA!

Answer (score 5):

Use detach if you need to [preserve existing jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

```
var twitpar = $('#twitter');
var twit = $('#twitter').detach();
```

then to reattach:

```
twitpar.append(twit);
```

Comment: `detach()` removes the selected element, so `twitpar = $("#twitter").parent();`.

Answer (score 1):

you can .clone() what you want

you can replaceWith() what you want

;)

Answer (score 0):

you have such a weird case and code here.

After remove it, you need to add or append it again.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var $one = $('#1');
    var $two = $('#2'); 
     var $twitter = $('#twitter');
            $one.click(function () {
                $one.hide();
                $two.show();
                $twitter.remove();
            });

            $two.click(function () {
                $one.show();
                $two.hide();
                $twitter.parent().append('<input id="twitter" type="hidden" name="twitter" value="yes"/>');
            });
 });
```

instead of 'hard-coding' the element, you can use template like jQuery template or mustache.js, etc.

usually I use iCanHaz. so that the code could be like this

```
$twitter.parent().append(ich.twitter({value: 'yes'});
```

and you define the twitter in

```
<script id="twitter" type="text/html">
<input id="twitter" type="hidden" name="twitter" value="{{value}}"/>
</script>
```